# How do I remove a HTML tag from a string I query from an API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, vite

I am querying an API that returns
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYpLX.png)

```
<p> text.. </p>.  <b> title</b>
```

The problem is that the string has a html tag, I want to know how can I remove this tag or failing that it works.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is the API returning and were are you getting this string of HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this tag RegExp to remove all tags form a certain string

```js
const tagRegExp =  new RegExp('<\s*[^>]*>', 'g')


let test = "<a>Some random.... </a><p> lorem ipsum </p>";

test = test.replace(tagRegExp, '');


console.log(test)
```